# Puppet won't execute command

Tags: puppet

Puppet 0.25.4 on ubuntu point blank refuses to execute the following command:

```
exec {"initiate replica set":
    command => "echo 'rs.initiate()' | mongo",
    path => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
    user => "root",
    require => Class["mongodb"]
}
```

I can execute the command as root myself, so I'm guessing perhaps it's an issue with the shell. Unfortunately upgrading puppet isn't an option (and causes other issues anyway).

I've tried specifying explicit paths to the binaries instead of relying on the path parameter, and also changing the command to:

```
"bash -c \"echo 'rs.initiate()' | mongo\""
```

Still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

I get an error message saying something like "failed to change from notrun to 0"

Answer (score 2):

See what the command actually returns when run as shell from root by running `echo $?` after running the actual command, probably it returns not 0. If so you need to change the statement to:

```
exec {"initiate replica set":
    command => "echo 'rs.initiate()' | mongo",
    path => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
    user => "root",
    require => Class["mongodb"],
    returns => $ActualReturnCode
}
```

Where $ActualReturnCode is the code that you get from `echo $?` after running the command as root.

There is one more thing about mongodb I forgot to mention - when you install the package it will take some time for the main mongodb database to init, until then you won't be able to access it. Thus the workaround here would be to also add sleep and a number of retries making the code look like:

```
exec {"initiate replica set":
    command => "echo 'rs.initiate()' | mongo",
    path => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
    user => "root",
    require => Class["mongodb"],
    retries => 5,
    sleep   => 60,
}
```

Comment: the problem is that it returns 1. i can't work out what shell puppet is using.

Comment: will if it returns one then you need to replace $ActualReturnCode with 1 making it thus: returns => 1 this should help

Comment: but the command fails. puppet seems to execute the command in a way that means it never runs successfully.

Comment: Check my last edit - just remembered one thing about mongodb and its puppetization process.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet 3 has new syntax for the exec resource type:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/types/exec.html

as such, the code from LogicWreck and Golja is a bit out of date.  The parameter `retries` is now `tries` and the `sleep` parameter is now `try_sleep`.

```
  exec { 'rs.initiate()':
     command     => 'echo "rs.initiate()" | mongo',
     path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
     user        => root,
     require     => Service[mongodb],
     tries       => 5,
     try_sleep   => 60,
     unless      => 'echo "rs.status()" | mongo | grep "members"'
  }
```

You might consider using an 'unless' or 'onlyif' parameter in there so that your resource is only evaluated when first setting up the replica set.

Answer (score 0):

One way do it is is:

```
exec {"initiate replica set":
      command => mongo admin /path/to/init.js",
      path => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
      user => "root",
      require => Class["mongodb"],
      sleep => 60,
      retries => 5,
}
```

Where the init.js is:

```
res = rs.initiate()
printjson(res)
```

This will return 0 if the command was executed without error. Use `printjson(res)` just for dev/debug mode. Later on you can get rid of it.

Also as Logic Wreck said make sure to use `sleep`, because initiate can take few seconds to finish.